# Text to Image API

Tags: reactjs, image, text

Can someone please suggest me some Free API's for Text to Image AI Tool only for developing purpose.!

I got this API
https://rapidapi.com/seikan/api/img4me-text-to-image-service/

When I research some API I got this API and can someone tell me is this good for my application?
I am creating it in react!

Comment: Please describe, What are you trying to do actually, So, we can help you in a better way.

Comment: I want to create the app in react "Text to image" if i write some text  in the input field the image should come related to the word like the AI tool have can you please share some free API for the same?

Comment: You exactly want to generate images like given text or some similar kinds ? I mean, Writing Lion gives an image with text "Lion" or real lion pictures ?

Comment: yes exactly if I write lion the real image of the lion should come also i want to make the image download

Comment: I am providing you some links and solutions as an answer below.

Comment: Try below solutions and mark answer as accepted if it helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know two different ways for this.

**1) DALL·E OpenAI**

openAI release an API for this named "DALL·E OpenAI". It can help you to create image based on given text as well as description.

Here, are some of the articles which you can explore for implementation purpose.

**Official Documentation:** https://openai.com/blog/dall-e-api-now-available-in-public-beta

Some implemetation techniques in ReactJS:

1. https://betterprogramming.pub/build-a-react-app-using-dall-e-api-bd15d5d67b31
2. https://www.makeuseof.com/react-dall-e-image-generator-application-build-api/
3. https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/generate-images-using-react-and-dall-e-api-react-and-openai-api-tutorial/

To know more in detail: https://openai.com/research/dall-e

**2) Unsplash API**

It is one of the most used and popular photo search engines.

Here, is the implementation technique using ReactJS:

1. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-build-a-photo-search-app-with-react-using-the-unsplash-api

Let me know if you have any doubt.

Comment: thanks let me try out this one and will let you know

Comment: hey, i am getting error in service worker file as in my project this file does exists and we need to add this file i think  https://gist.github.com/robdodson/7915c77e05a293c1a4033da5619dfc54 is this the file i can add right?

Comment: Compiled with problems:
×
ERROR in ./src/index.js 8:0-49
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './serviceWorker' in 'C:\CV\Text-to-image-app\texttoimage\src'

error occured in project

Comment: Which method you're using ?

Comment: function method

Comment: import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

reportWebVitals();
serviceWorker.unregister();

Comment: this is the code

Comment: I meant to say, Which link you're following from mentioned link ?

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-build-a-photo-search-app-with-react-using-the-unsplash-api

Comment: You don't need to remove anything from default template!! It's fine to keep as it is. Just Remove code from App.css and Index.css files and keep these files empty. and, than start from Step 2 directly.

Comment: And, If you've created your project using "create react app" - You don't need to worry about serviceworkers and all. All the things will be taken care automatically.

Comment: okay got it let me try and will get back to you thanks

Comment: 2) Unsplash API

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-build-a-photo-search-app-with-react-using-the-unsplash-api    "This works for me thanks "